# How to pass variable into a onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

I am wanting to try and pass record.ItemID to my onclick = buy() function. But I am getting errors like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"

I have tried \"record.ItemID \" but that of course just passes the literal string of result.name

I have also tried (\'' + record.ItemID + '\') but get the same Syntax error

```
function showShop(items) {
   let tableContent = "<tr class='orderTitle'><td =imgTable></td><td id = contentTable ></td></tr>\n";
   let odd = true;
   const addRecord = (record) => {
    tableContent += odd ? "<tr class='orderOdd'>" : "<tr class='orderEven'>";
      odd = !odd;
      tableContent += "<td>" + "<img id = image src="+ "http://redsox.uoa.auckland.ac.nz/ms/MuseumService.svc/shopimg?id=" + record.ItemId  + " />" +  "</td><td id = content>" + record.Description + "<td><button  onclick='buy("+ record.ItemId +")'/> Buy </button></td>";

   }


   items.forEach(addRecord)
   document.getElementById("shop").innerHTML = tableContent;

}





function buy(item){

  window.open('http://redsox.uoa.auckland.ac.nz/mss/Service.svc/buy?id='+ item,'_self');


}
```

Comment: Can you post more context? Where is `tableContent` being used?

Comment: `tableContent` is used in another function

Comment: Please post the full code around `tableContent`

Comment: ```<button  onclick=buy(" + record.ItemId + ")/> Buy </button>``` should work

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/1qLfd3K) sorry I cannot seem to paste it in as it was too big

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: hi there sorry, i have just edited now

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will solve your problem but it looks like you're mixing up `'`s and `"`s.

```
onclick='buy('record.ItemId')'
```

You are terminating the `onclick` attribute right after `buy(`.

You may need to do something like:

```
onclick='buy(" + record.ItemId + ")'
```

Generally speaking though, if you *have* to build up HTML in strings, you are better off string interpolation. It makes it easier to read and is less prone to these types of issues.

Example:

```
const html = `<button onclick="buy(${record.ItemId})">Click</button>`;
```

Answer (score 0):

The General format of onclick is

```
onclick="function_name(variable)"
```

For this case you can do something like this:

```
tableContent += '<td>' + '<img id = image src="http://redsox.uoa.auckland.ac.nz/ms/MuseumService.svc/shopimg?id=' + record.ItemId  + '" /></td><td id="content">' + record.Description + '<td><button onclick="buy('+record.ItemId+')"> Buy </button></td>';
```

Comment: thank you all, this pretty much  has worked to what i was wanted but i think it is passing the itemID i want as a variable? [screenshot](https://imgur.com/ah7i8Tm)

Comment: What is bb-hat? I think it is considering bb minus hat.

Comment: bb-hat is the ID for an item that i want to be passed to the buy function to get the item. But yes I think you are right it is passing it as an equation.

Comment: bb-hat is ID then it should be as a string in quotes. like this 'bb-hat' or "bb-hat".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to build up some HTML content to put into a table, and you want some behaviour attached to a button inside the table so that it opens a new window when you click on it.

There are a number of different approaches to what you're trying to do which would be safer in production code, so while you've got some answers to your specific question, please consider these alternative approaches which are more idiomatic:

1. You could use a link (`<a>`) instead of a button, and use CSS to make the link look like a button. This avoids needing a click handler at all.
2. You could use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store the record in a safe way, then access it from the click event, e.g. `e.target.dataset.recordId`.
3. You could use jQuery or a similar toolkit to create the button, then attach a function to the button as a click handler.

When you create HTML directly like you are doing in your question, you're opening your code up to [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection), where someone malicious could craft data that could steal private information from users of your site. It's much safer to use a library to construct your HTML directly rather than building it up in strings.

Answer (score 0):

Really you're much better off separating out your inline JS and using event listeners to target classes on your elements.

Here's a quick example to show you how you might achieve that:

```js
const records = [{ itemId: 1 }, { itemId: 2 }, { itemId: 3 }];
const imgRoot = 'https://dummyimage.com/30x30/676767/fff.png?id=';

// `map` iterates over the array and produces one element of HTML per record
// We use a class on the button to identify it, and a data attribute
// button to hold the itemId
const html = records.map(({ itemId }) => {
  return `
    <div class="itemWrapper">
      <img class="item" src="${imgRoot}${itemId}" />
      <button data-itemid="${itemId}" class="buyRecord">Buy record</button>
    </div>
  `;
});

document.querySelector('.root').innerHTML = html.join('');
 
// We grab the buttons and iterate over them attaching
// event listeners that call `handleBuy` when the button is clicked
const buyButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.buyRecord');
buyButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', handleBuy, false));

function handleBuy(e) {

  // Destructure the itemid from the dataset of the button
  // click event
  const { target: { dataset: { itemid } } } = e;
  console.log(itemid);
}
```

```html
<div class="root" />
```

Documentation

- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)